# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Inside Docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I have problem in connecting mysql from inside Docker to MySQL which is hosted on host vm. I use Laravel and these are my mysql .ENV connection file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_PORT=33161
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=laravel_user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I can run the apps normally means that it's connected to mysql database, but when I go to inside Docker through:

```
 docker exec -it ContainerName /bin/sh
```

and I type:

```
php artisan migrate
```

This error appears:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again
```

This IP 172.17.0.1 is my host IP on Docker network. I have tried by changing it with hostname, or changed it to local ip like 127.0.0.1 or changed it to vm network IP but it still not connected from inside docker.

I'm confuse how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: DB_HOST=172.17.0.1 change to your mysql container name

Comment: I only run single Docker which is running Laravel, and MySQL is installed on VM not on Docker.

Comment: I also has tried by putting my VM hostname and it still not working.

Comment: Try to ping in the docker on your WM mysql server's ip

Comment: Both can reply, I tried ping from host to docker and from docker to host.